# facebook - using FBJS in iframe applications

Tags: facebook, fbjs

I am trying to use FBJS in my iframe app. Nothing that I write seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I thought the whole point of an iframe Facebook app was so you could use your own JS instead of Facebook's subset? The iframe is sandboxed from the user's Facebook, so it's safe for Facebook - you can't access FB's internals. FBJS was invented so you could use JS in profile boxes and canvas apps without being able to screw with the rest of the Facebook functionality.

Comment: what is your definition of  FB's internals?

Comment: Facebook doesn't want you mucking around with anything on the site outside your app. Allowing normal JavaScript in a canvas app would mean you could change things in Facebook's layout - you could make the "Home" link go somewhere else, for example.

iframe apps can't touch anything outside the iframe, so it's safe for Facebook to allow full JavaScript there instead of the limited subset that is FBJS.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Facebook connect to access FBJS calls.

Facebook encourages Iframe developers to use Facebook Connect to perform client-side facebook interaction, such as publishing feed stories, permission dialogs, etc.

See:
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Creating_a_Popup_Dialog_in_an_IFrame

Comment: From my perspective anyhow, it's not about the login dialogs, but about the DOM manipulation stuff that Facebook added via FBJS.  We've got a lot of old code that needs to be migrated to iframes, and the quickest way to do that would be to just make FBJS work inside the iframe.  Looks like Facebook took their stuff from prototype.js so I think we're going to start by including that instead of fbjs.